# Why is there no guayadeque in 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, music-player, official-repositories

I noticed today that there is no [Guayadeque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guayadeque_Music_Player) in Ubuntu 16.04.  It was there in 15.10.

Such a cool player, I couldn't find it in Ubuntu Xenial repository.

- Could anyone point out a reference for Ubuntu decision to drop it? or any related discussion?
- How to install Guayadeque in Ubuntu Xenial?

Comment: Late welcome to Ask Ubuntu, I would say it, the way you asked brings much down votes and will do more. I think you need to *Make it relevant to others* (reference: https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask). I will make an edit trial if you don't like or disagree , feel free to roll it back (through [edit history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/761984/revisions)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Guayadeque have now gstreamer 1.0 support. See http://github.com/anonbeat/guayadeque. Porting code to wx3.0 is in progress.

Instructions to build from source:

> First go to a folder where you have write permissions. In this folder
>   you are going to create a `guayadeque` folder and compile it from
>   there.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install git build-essential cmake gettext
> sudo apt-get install libwxgtk3.0-dev libtag1-dev libwxsqlite3-3.0-dev libsqlite3-dev 
> sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libdbus-1-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgpod-dev libindicate-dev
> cd folder_where_to_create_the_program
> git clone https://github.com/anonbeat/guayadeque.git
> cd guayadeque
> ./build
> sudo make install
> ```
>
> With that you should have it compiled from source and installed.

([Source](http://guayadeque.org/index.php?p=/discussion/1868/gstreamer-1-0-and-wxwidgets-3-0-porting-bug-reports-#Item_2))

Comment: I am trying to intall by source, but I cannot find the packages that provides the dependencies... would you list them? For example, there is no `taglib-dev` anywhere in repos... Thanks!

Comment: Build fails with error:


    src/CMakeFiles/guayadeque.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target
    src/CMakeFiles/guayadeque.dir/AlListBox.o' failed
    make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/guayadeque.dir/AlListBox.o] Error 1
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:181: recipe for target
    src/CMakeFiles/guayadeque.dir/all' failed
    make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/guayadeque.dir/all] Error 2
    Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2

Answer (score 5):

From [the publishing history on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/guayadeque):

> Removal requested on 2016-02-05.
>   Deleted on 2016-02-05 by Steve Langasek
>   (From Debian) RoQA; dead upstream; depends on gstreamer 0.10; Debian
>   bug [#810251](http://bugs.debian.org/810251)

It's a consequence of [Debian deciding to remove gstreamer0.10](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2015/05/msg00335.html) from their next release:

> We shouldn't include GStreamer 0.10 in the next release, and only ship
>   the new 1.x release series. This was also suggested by the security
>   team a while ago.
>
> GStreamer 0.10 is no longer maintained and supported by the upstream
>   project since almost 3 years now, and contains many known bugs that
>   are fixed in the new 1.x release series of GStreamer. Next to many bug
>   fixes, the new release series also contains many other improvements,
>   new features and a more streamlined API.

gstreamer0.10 is still available in Ubuntu 16.04's repositories, presumably because the removal in Debian happened too late in 16.04's development. However, the removal of guayadeque happened early, it was removed from Ubuntu as well.

Comment: Thanks very much muru.  I did some more looking based on your note and I see this on the Guayadeque forums: http://guayadeque.org/index.php?p=/discussion/1851/is-guauydeque-still-alive

Answer (score 4):

It is now possible to install Guayadeque on Ubuntu 16.04 from a PPA (private repository) created by the author anonbeat.

In a terminal type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:anonbeat/guayadeque
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install guayadeque
```

For details see: https://launchpad.net/~anonbeat/+archive/ubuntu/guayadeque