# How to install Guayadeque on 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, music-player

I've seen on this post ([Why is there no guayadeque in 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761984/why-is-there-no-guayadeque-in-16-04/764419#764419)) why there is no Guayadeque in the repositories in 16.04, but how can we install it ?

We should be able to do it if we install gstreamer0.10 and download the latest version here (https://sourceforge.net/projects/guayadeque/files/) ?

Answer (score 5):

Guayadeque has been updated and it is now possible to install it on Ubuntu 16.04 from a PPA (private repository) created by the author anonbeat.

In a terminal type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:anonbeat/guayadeque
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install guayadeque
```

For details see: https://launchpad.net/~anonbeat/+archive/ubuntu/guayadeque

Answer (score 0):

Installing necessary things:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential cmake gettext
sudo apt-get install libwxgtk3.0-dev libtag1-dev libwxsqlite3-3.0-dev libsqlite3-dev 
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libdbus-1-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgpod-dev libindicate-dev
```

Install Guayadeque in home directory (Write permission should be allowed in the directory):

```
cd $HOME
```

Installing Guayadeque:

```
git clone https://github.com/anonbeat/guayadeque.git
cd guayadeque
./build
sudo make install
```

*Guayadeque installation in now in your $HOME/guayadeque*

To update:

```
cd ~/guayadeque
git pull
./build
sudo make install
```

[Source](http://www.guayadeque.org/index.php?p=/discussion/1868/gstreamer-1-0-and-wxwidgets-3-0-porting-bug-reports-#Item_2)

Comment: same error as before 
"Your GStreamer  installation is missing a plug-in"